# Is there a similar function like "calculate order" in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a bunch of edges that I extrude procedurally using the screw modifier. I would like to do this in geometry nodes. However, when I extrude it using geometry nodes, some of the corners are flipped.

[image: flipped corners]
[image]

In the screw modifier, this could be fixed simply by clicking on the "Calculate Order" checkbox.
[image]

[image]
[image]

I would like the same function in geometry nodes. Thank you!